# RecyclerView: How to tell not to recycle?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with expandable list items. That means when the user clicks on an item it gets expanded and additional information is appearing. If the user is clicking again the item gets collapsed so that the additional information is hiding again.

My problem now is the following:

When i expand the first item and scroll down a bit and up again the first item is collapsed again automatically but the internal state ofcourse still is at the expanded state so i cant expand it anymore. Also when the first item is expanded and i scroll down some of the items are in the expanded state too without showing the additional data and i cant expand it anymore.

So that means i have to somehow disable the recycling mechanic. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think disabling the recycling mechanic is the wrong solution. The whole idea of the recyclerview is to do this. What you need to do is to preserve the state